# Conditional grouped barplot R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, bar-chart

I am trying to make a `barplot` in R for two categorical variables, `Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2` and `phq9_cat`. `phq9_cat` has two levels, `0` and `1`, where `0` corresponds to `PHQ-L` and `1` corresponds to `PHQ-H`.

Here is my code:

```
# get counts of vars
counts <- table(data2$Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2, data2$phq9_cat)

# get percentages of vars
pcnts <- scale(counts, FALSE, colSums(counts))*100

# plot barplot
bp <- barplot(pcnts, beside=TRUE, col=c("azure3", "azure4"), ylab="Frequency (%)", border=NA)
legend("topright", legend=c("PHQ-L", "PHQ-H"), bty="n", fill=c("azure3", "azure4"), border=NA)
text(bp, 1, round(pcnts, 2), cex=1, pos=3, col=c("black"))
```

And the resulting plot:

[image]

Which is great! But I need to only plot the `data2$Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2==1` category. So I would like a barplot with only the `3.03` bar and the `19.44` bar.

I've exhausted any clever tricks that I know of already such as making the `data2$Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2==0` bars white and using `space = c(-1, 0)` to make the `data2$Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2==1` bars next to one another but then the bars are super wide, like so:

[image]

I just need the `data2$Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2==1` columns, but at a normal width.

Any ideas?

Here is my data:

```
> dput(data2)
structure(list(Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), phq9_cat = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Dep_meds_at_time_of_rx_2", "phq9_cat"), row.names = c(NA, 
-243L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minor revision of what you have. I think it gets close to accomplishing what you want:

```
bp <- barplot(pcnts[2,], beside=TRUE, col=c("azure3", "azure4"), ylab="Frequency (%)",
              border=NA)
legend("topleft", legend=c("PHQ-L", "PHQ-H"), bty="n", fill=c("azure3", "azure4"), border=NA)
text(bp[], 1, round(pcnts[2,], 2), cex=1, pos=3, col=c("black"))
```

Note that if it is desired to drop the "0" "1" labels on the x axis, you can accomplish this by replacing `pcnts[2, ]` with `unname(pcnts)` in the first line:

```
bp <- barplot(unname(pcnts[2, ]), beside=TRUE, col=c("azure3", "azure4"),
              ylab="Frequency (%)", border=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to select the second row of `pcnts` in the text() command as well or you'll get overlapping labels.

Comment: aye, thanks. I had that but must have copied an earlier version.

Comment: Thank you! This is great. Don't know why I couldn't remember how to select the second row of the table. I'll pretend it's Monday.

Comment: Shouldn't both of the labels for the x-axis be 1?

Comment: @bouncyball It looks like the labels are pulled from the column names of `pcnts`, which is the variable `data2$phq9_cat`. Having the labels differ is probably more informative then having uniform labels.

Comment: But the original (albeit uniform) labels _are_ informative. I would argue that either there should be no labels on the x-axis and instead have a descriptive title, or have uniform labels with an x-axis title.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd throw in a `ggplot2` answer. This solution ensures that both of the labels on the x-axis are 1 - reflecting the status of Anti-depressant use:

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(Frequency = pcnts[2,],
                   PHQ = c('PHQ-L','PHQ-H'))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = 1, y = Frequency))+
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = PHQ), 
             position = position_dodge(width = 1))+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('PHQ-L' = 'azure3',
                                 'PHQ-H' = 'azure4'),
                      name = '')+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(.75, 1.25),
                       labels = c(1,1))+
    xlab('Anti-Depressant use at time of treatment')+
    ylab('Frequency (%)')+
    geom_text(x = .75, y = 2.5, label = '19.44%')+
    geom_text(x = 1.25, y = 2.5, label = '3.03%')+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is really useful, as I did try to figure it out in `ggplot` as well. I'll have to try this next time. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to select the second row of your percentages table, e.g.

```
# get percentages of vars
pcnts <- scale(counts, FALSE, colSums(counts))*100
# Filter for the results you want
pcnts <- pcnts[2, ]
# Plot as before
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Upped one but someone got to the answer sooner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve narrow bars then a combination of width and space arguments will do the trick.

```
barplot(pcnts, beside=TRUE, col=c("azure3", "azure4"), ylab="Frequency (%)", border=NA, width = c(0,.51, 0,0.51), space = c(1,2))
```

[image]

or you can change the colour to white

```
barplot(pcnts, beside=TRUE, col=c("white", "azure4"), ylab="Frequency (%)", border=NA,  space = c(1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Up voted for use of the `width` and `space` arguments, I didn't look at that combo before. The labels just aren't centered with the bars. Looks like selecting the 2nd row of `pcnts` is what I was looking for. Thanks!